# iOS - Isometric grid image problems

Tags: ios, grid, isometric

I have a myriad of `UIImageViews` that act as 'tiles' on a map. They align up next to one another to form a grid of images. The `layer` of each `UIImageView` is added as a sublayer of a `UIView`.

Ordinarily, the grid images are flush against each other, but whenever the `UIScrollView` that contains the `UIView` is zoomed in or out, the spaces between the tile images become visible, showing off the grid pattern that I'd like to be invisible.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to create a CATiledLayer from scratch...?

Why not just use CATiledLayer?

Comment: I'll be honest, I haven't found a simple tutorial that I've been able to follow. I've also read a few articles saying that there are a lot of limitations that I didn't want to face later on.

Comment: It's hard to get going with them. I'll maybe put up a tutorial tonight and link it.